# Scala "balance the scopes" recursion

Tags: scala, recursion

I write code, which checks brackets balances in a string:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

      def scopes(chars: List[Char], s: Int): Boolean = {
        if (chars.isEmpty)
          if (s == 0) true
          else false
        else{
          if (s < 0) return false
          if (chars.head.toString == "(") scopes(chars.tail, s + 1)
          if (chars.head.toString == ")") scopes(chars.tail, s - 1)


          else scopes(chars.tail, s)
        }
      }
      scopes(chars, 0)
    }
balance("if zero? x( max / 1 x".toList)
```

But it works wrong. I just can not find the mistake. Need help with it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `else` in the nested `if ...` block: the first recursive call to `scopes` has no effect, because it always gets overriden by `scopes(chars.tail, s)` ...

In general, `if..else` blocks, especially nested ones, are usually better written as a `match` clause, that can be more readable and less prone to errors like this one. Also, `return` statements are bad, and should (almost) never be used in scala.

```
 @tailrec
 def scopes(chars: List[Char], s: Int = 0): Boolean = chars match {
   case Nil => s == 0
   case _ if s < 0 => false
   case "(" :: tail => scopes(tail, s+1)
   case ")" :: tail => scopes(tail, s-1)
   case _ :: tail => scopes(tail, s)
 }
```

Also, I recommend using `@tailrec` tag everywhere you expect the algorithm to be tail-recursive. In your case, for instance, using that tag would have caught the error at compile time - the first recursive call to `scopes` is not in the tail position, although it should be.

Comment: haha, so impatient of me - thanks!